# How many dotted points I would make to fit them under the word in CSS

Tags: html, css

I tried to make an under-line dotted under word to mark it as user provided information.

It is fine to use a pre-defined html under-line tag `<u>..</u>` with styling `dotted` or style `border-bottom`. However, it is a little bit problem with printing (the dotted not showing correctly); Therefore I decided to use dotted symbols `...` instead because it is showing correct and precise.

By that way, I tried to make the word takes place of dotted points' spaces, and dotted point would stay a little bit lower from it current position under the word.

To make it clear, it would look like this:

[image: Word dotted underline]

My HTML Code do to this is like so:

```css
.dotted:before{
  content: '..................';
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>Name: <span class="dotted">Jonh David</span></p>
```

However, as the information provided by user is varied, I cannot determined how many dotted points I would need to fit those information correctly.

Your tip is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder what is the problem with underline or you could try `border-bottom: 1px dotted #444` but whatever, here's your method - a span with dotted :pseudo - which takes into account the length of the element.

- content is a lot of … (use dots if you wish)
- it's cropped with `overflow: hidden`
- test cases with 2 very different lengths

3rd example is good ole dotted border (works since IE7)

```css
.dotted {
  position: relative;
}

.dotted:before{
  content: '…………………………………………………………………………………………';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.other-dots {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<p>Name: <span class="dotted">Jonh David</span></p>

<p>Name: <span class="dotted">Maria-Magdalena von Stroheim de la Peña</span></p>

<p>Name: <span class="other-dots">Other way with bd-bottom</span></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Can use border-bottom-style css property

```
.dotted {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom-style: dotted;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j965444n/

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry not to mention also that using `<u>` tag and style `border-bottom` are a little problem with printing (not showing dotted point correctly as it look on browser). Therefore, I tried to use dotted symbol instead, I will edit my question to include border-bottom as well. :)

Comment: @HouyNarun ahhh sorry. I wasn't sure in what capacity `<u>` was being utilized.

Answer (score 3):

I found this really cool site for doing this. Refer the site below.

<kbd>**Styling Underlines**</kbd>

You can play around with the properties and get the desired thickness and padding, also this is not dependent on setting the width based on the content size!

Check my below example of how this is done!

```css
.dotted {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000000 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-position: 0px 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 4px 2px;
  padding: 0px 3px;
}
```

```html
<p>Name: <span class="dotted">Jonh David</span></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's something like this:

```
#myDIV {
text-decoration: underline;
text-decoration-style:dotted;}
```

[w3schools underline](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_text-decoration-style&preval=double)

**Note**: The text-decoration-style is only supported by Firefox.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, However it does not show any dotted point.

Comment: Can you include jsfiddle? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If [a simple dotted border](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/oGbzgv) isn't good enough for you and say you want to control the spacing between the dots - you could make your technique work by setting `overflow:hidden` on the parent element.

```css
.dotted {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.dotted:before {
  content: '...............................';
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  letter-spacing: 2px; /* adjust to control spacing between dots */
}
```

```html
<p>Name: <span class="dotted">Jonh David</span></p>

<p>Name: <span class="dotted">Jo</span></p>

<p>Name: <span class="dotted">Jonh David blabla</span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think @Christopher Marshall's idea is gonna make the same effect on printed page, so here is an example with background : https://codepen.io/Pauloscorps/pen/YrwWYo

HTML

```
<p>My name is : <span>John David</span></p>
```

CSS :

```
p {
  span {
    display:inline-block;
    font-weight:bold;
    &:after {
      content:"";
      display:block;
      width:100%;
      height:1px;
      background:red url('https://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/194508dot.jpg') repeat center bottom;;
    }
  }
}
```